# Mongo aggregation on array elements

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a mongo document like

```
{ "_id" : 12, "location" : [ "Kannur","Hyderabad","Chennai","Bengaluru"] }
{ "_id" : 13, "location" : [ "Hyderabad","Chennai","Mysore","Ballary"] }
```

From this how can I get the location aggregation (distinct area count).
some thing like

```
Hyderabad 2, 
Kannur 1, 
Chennai 2, 
Bengaluru 1, 
Mysore 1, 
Ballary 1
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Using aggregation you cannot get the exact output that you want. One of the limitations of aggregation pipeline is its inability to transform `values` to `keys` in the output document.

For example, `Kannur` is one of the values of the `location` field, in the input document. In your desired output structure it needs to be the `key("kannur":1)`. This is not possible using aggregation. While, this can be used achieving `map-reduce`, you can however get a very closely related and useful structure using aggregation.

- `Unwind` the location array.
- `Group` by the location fields, get the count of individual locations
  using the $sum operator.
- `Group` again all the documents once again to get a consolidated array
  of results.

Code:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$unwind:"$location"},
{$group:{"_id":"$location","count":{$sum:1}}},
{$group:{"_id":null,"location_details":{$push:{"location":"$_id",
                                               "count":"$count"}}}},
{$project:{"_id":0,"location_details":1}}
])
```

Sample o/p:

```
{
        "location_details" : [
                {
                        "location" : "Ballary",
                        "count" : 1
                },
                {
                        "location" : "Mysore",
                        "count" : 1
                },
                {
                        "location" : "Bengaluru",
                        "count" : 1
                },
                {
                        "location" : "Chennai",
                        "count" : 2
                },
                {
                        "location" : "Hyderabad",
                        "count" : 2
                },
                {
                        "location" : "Kannur",
                        "count" : 1
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. one more query please. Can we get only one specific location count? Like Hyderabad 2

Comment: Yes you could add a `$match:{location:"hyderabad"}` stage after the `$unwind` stage. Please do consider accepting the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: Can the same is applicable for integer array? when i apply the same on integer array, i am getting like this  -- uncaught exception: aggregate failed: {
 "errmsg" : "exception: Value at end of $unwind field path '$list_id' must be an Array, but is a NumberInt32",
 "code" : 15978,
 "ok" : 0
}

Comment: @SURYAGOKARAJU - Yes. it can be applied on an integer array. The error seems to occur because some of the documents have a integer value in the field instead of an array. We can discuss it more on it here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70508/mongodb.

Comment: if the `locations` are `mongo id` and we want to populate the `name` of the `mongo id` , how do we go about it? any suggestion?